# Split multiple strings in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel with some data separated by ";" in a cell.
I need to split that cell, and some subsequent one, so that splitted content will go each to a new line each.
Example:

```
Column f    Column j     Column k
a;b;c       d;e;f        g;h;i
```

Should become

```
a         d       g
b         e       h
c         f       i
```

This is what i have, but not working:

```
Sub tgr()

Dim rindex As Long
Dim saItem() As String
Dim sbItem() As String
Dim scItem() As String

For rindex = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Cells(rindex, "F").Value, ";") > 0 Then
        saItem = Split(Cells(rindex, "F").Value, ";")
        sbItem = Split(Cells(rindex, "J").Value, ";")
        scItem = Split(Cells(rindex, "K").Value, ";")
        Rows(rindex + 1 & ":" & rindex + UBound(saItem)).Insert
        Cells(rindex, "F").Resize(UBound(saItem) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(saItem)
        Cells(rindex, "J").Resize(UBound(sbItem) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sbItem)
        Cells(rindex, "K").Resize(UBound(scItem) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scItem)
    End If
Next rindex

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you code is working for me as expected. What is wrong in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong array for Col K. I guess you copy pasted and forgot to change it? :)

Replace the line

`Cells(rindex, "K").Resize(UBound(sbItem) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sbItem)`

with

`Cells(rindex, "K").Resize(UBound(scItem) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scItem)`